# Formal Names for Groups of 1-14

Tags: numbers

What are names for counting measurements for items 1 through 14 that fit in a sentence such as:

> I want a(n) ____ egg(s).

What I think so far:

1. Singular, Solitary
2. Couple
3. ?
4. ?
5. ?
6. Half-Dozen
7. ?
8. ?
9. ?
10. ?
11. ?
12. Dozen
13. ?
14. ?

### Update:

The purpose of this is to describe a base-14 number system in English-ish terms.

Saying, "Twelve" for example, implies "(1*10) + (1*2)=12", which is then interpreted to mean "::::::".

I am looking for a words such as "Dozen," which, for this example, already implies the concept "::::::" without the "(X*10) + Y" monkey business.

Comment: You left out half-dozen.

Comment: Where have you already looked while searching for this information?

Comment: I have searched google and Merriam-Webster for terms referring to numerical denominations.

Comment: Triplet, quartet, quintet, sextet, septet, octet, nonet, dectet, undectet, duodectet, tredectet.  Beyond that you need a Latin scholar.

Comment: @HotLicks, these numerical number sets don't quite fit: "I want an octet eggs."

Comment: Yet you list "pair of" as an option.

Comment: Oops xD Fixed it.

Comment: 13 = "baker's dozen"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on multiple misconceptions. *Twelve* is no more decimal-related than *two*: none of these words (whether OPs or other suggestions) are formal in any way (rather informal, so that in many senses *a couple* can include three): and  all except *dozen* require 'of' to connect them to the thing counted.

Comment: @TimLymington _Eleven_ and _twelve_ are historically as ten-based as _thirteen_ and _fourteen_ (which is the number asked about here, not twelve); it's just not as transparent. Then again, so is _dozen_.

Comment: There were, in ancient times, several cultures which employed the duodecimal numbering system.  One assumes that they would have had names for eleven and twelve which were based on decimal.

Comment: Oops -- I mean **not** based on decimal.

Answer (score 3):

For *eggs* specifically the only two that really fit are half-dozen (6) and baker's dozen (13).

Technically you could use the [polyad](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/polyad) names: monad, dyad, triad, etc. but they aren't in everyday use.  Also you'd have to add "of" ... "I want a triad of eggs."

There are also [chamber music group names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_ensemble#Classical_chamber_music):  trio, quartet, quintet, etc.  You could maybe get away with asking for a trio or quartet of eggs, but anything beyond that is going to get odd looks.

Why not just use the numbers?  I'd like seven eggs please.

Comment: I just added an update to hopefully explain my intentions better.

Comment: @ilcj I still think you're going astray with your question.  "Dozen" only has meaning because it ties back to **twelve**.  Same with all the other words on your list.  Humans think in base-10, so they're going to translate a group of three eggs as "three eggs" regardless of whether you're writing the quantity in base-10, base-2, or base-14.  Even the polyad names translate to base-10 numeric roots (two, three, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

A brace also means a quantity of two: a brace of knives.

http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=brace